# How i can create button as shown in picture?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

[image]

How i can create dynamic component as shown in picture? Component image could be change at run time.
Component border and backgrond color should be changable at run time.

Comment: Just do `setBackground()`, `setBorder()` and `setIcon()` when you need to (probably inside a listener like an `ActionListener`). That should work just fine.

Comment: But how i can render image inside camera icon as shown in picture

Comment: My ideas would be to either make images of all combinations and use them, or, add a new JPanel with transparency to the button with a `GridLayout(2, 2)` and add panels with the corresponding image (like the bell) to it. (The camera would be the icon of the whole button)

Comment: I'd use a variation of this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Button as below,

```
JButton button = new JButton();

try {
    Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/water.bmp"));
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //catch exceptions
}
```

You can call

```
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

To change the button image at run time.

You can call

```
button.setBackground()
```

to change the background at runtime.

Have a look at [JButton Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) for more information.